# GNU make: build all sources in a different directory

Tags: makefile

Given:

```
programs := apps/prog1 apps/prog2        # the actual list is quite long
sources := src/prog1.cpp src/prog2.cpp   # showing only 2 files
```

Make file has 2 targets `release` and `debug`. Each target should build every program in `bin/` directory and appends target name to the file name.

For example, building `release` should create `bin/prog1_release` and `bin/prog2_release`.

How to write static pattern rule to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Is each executable compiled from a single C++ source file?

Comment: No, porg_i is compiled from prog_i.cpp

Comment: I meant is there always a 1 to 1 corespondence between a .cpp file and an executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it (in GNUMake 3.81):

```
BINS := $(patsubst apps/%,bin/%,$(programs))   # bin/prog1 bin/prog2 ...
release_bins := $(addsuffix _release,$(BINS))  # bin/prog1_release ...
debug_bins := $(addsuffix _debug,$(BINS))      # bin/prog1_debug ...

$(release_bins): bin/%_release: src/%.cpp
    #build the binaries according to the release rule

$(debug_bins): bin/%_debug: src/%.cpp
    #build the binaries according to the debug rule

release: $(release_bins)

debug: $(debug_bins)

.PHONY: release debug

# If it turns out that one of the progs needs something else too:
bin/prog20_debug: somethingElse.cpp
```

(There are ways to make this slightly more concise, but at the cost of clarity.)